# AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'dim' with pytorch and scipy.optimize minimize

Tags: python, scipy, pytorch

I have the following small code snippet:

```
import torch
from scipy.optimize import minimize 

def f(x):
    return torch.norm(x)

x = torch.tensor([1.0, 1.0])
y = minimize(f, x)
print(y)
```

However, this results in this error message:

```
> AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call
> last) <ipython-input-17-cb070be7a142> in <module>
>       6 
>       7 x = [1.0, 1.0]
> ----> 8 y = minimize(f, x)
>       9 print(y)
> 
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py in
> minimize(fun, x0, args, method, jac, hess, hessp, bounds, constraints,
> tol, callback, options)
>     610         return _minimize_cg(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)
>     611     elif meth == 'bfgs':
> --> 612         return _minimize_bfgs(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, **options)
>     613     elif meth == 'newton-cg':
>     614         return _minimize_newtoncg(fun, x0, args, jac, hess, hessp, callback,
> 
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py in
> _minimize_bfgs(fun, x0, args, jac, callback, gtol, norm, eps, maxiter, disp, return_all, finite_diff_rel_step, **unknown_options)    1100    
> 1101     sf = _prepare_scalar_function(fun, x0, jac, args=args,
> epsilon=eps,
> -> 1102                                   finite_diff_rel_step=finite_diff_rel_step)    1103     1104     f =
> sf.fun
> 
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\optimize.py in
> _prepare_scalar_function(fun, x0, jac, args, bounds, epsilon, finite_diff_rel_step, hess)
>     260     # calculation reduces overall function evaluations.
>     261     sf = ScalarFunction(fun, x0, args, grad, hess,
> --> 262                         finite_diff_rel_step, bounds, epsilon=epsilon)
>     263 
>     264     return sf
> 
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py
> in __init__(self, fun, x0, args, grad, hess, finite_diff_rel_step,
> finite_diff_bounds, epsilon)
>      74 
>      75         self._update_fun_impl = update_fun
> ---> 76         self._update_fun()
>      77 
>      78         # Gradient evaluation
> 
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py
> in _update_fun(self)
>     164     def _update_fun(self):
>     165         if not self.f_updated:
> --> 166             self._update_fun_impl()
>     167             self.f_updated = True
>     168 
> 
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py
> in update_fun()
>      71 
>      72         def update_fun():
> ---> 73             self.f = fun_wrapped(self.x)
>      74 
>      75         self._update_fun_impl = update_fun
> 
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_differentiable_functions.py
> in fun_wrapped(x)
>      68         def fun_wrapped(x):
>      69             self.nfev += 1
> ---> 70             return fun(x, *args)
>      71 
>      72         def update_fun():
> 
> <ipython-input-17-cb070be7a142> in f(x)
>       3 
>       4 def f(x):
> ----> 5     return torch.norm(x)
>       6 
>       7 x = [1.0, 1.0]
> 
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\functional.py in norm(input, p,
> dim, keepdim, out, dtype)
>     738         (tensor(3.7417), tensor(11.2250))
>     739     """
> --> 740     ndim = input.dim()
>     741 
>     742     # catch default case
> 
> AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'dim'
```

I'm not sure why this is happening as I don't think I'm converting anything to a numpy.ndarray.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you get it work with `numpy` instead of `torch`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use NumPy instead of torch.

```
import numpy
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def f(x):
    return numpy.linalg.norm(x)

x = numpy.array([1.0, 1.0])
y = minimize(f, x)
print(y)
```

Comment: Thanks this can work. However, I'm trying to apply this to a project that uses a lot of tensors. I probably could get away with converting the tensors to numpy arrays, but it will probably be instructive to understand what is causing the error in the first place.

Comment: `scipy` is `numpy` based, `minimize` converts your `x` to `ndarray` and passes that to `f`.. So `f` has to work with `ndarray`, and return a scalar.